# Android: change button background programmatically

Tags: android

I have this resource file for colors

```
<resources>
    <color name="CLR_BLUE">#00f</color>
    <color name="CLR_RED">#f00</color>
    <color name="CLR_GREEN">#0f0</color>
    <color name="CLR_YELLOW">#ff0</color>
    <color name="CLR_BLUE_DARK">#00a</color>
    <color name="CLR_RED_DARK">#a00</color>
    <color name="CLR_GREEN_DARK">#0a0</color>
    <color name="CLR_YELLOW_DARK">#aa0</color>
</resources>
```

And this method that gets called when the user clicks one of four colored `Buttons`

```
private void changeBackground(Button pressedBtn)
{
    int oldColor = 0;
    int newColor = 0;

    if(pressedBtn == greenBtn) {
        oldColor = R.color.CLR_GREEN;
        newColor = R.color.CLR_GREEN_DARK;
    }
    else if (pressedBtn == redBtn) {
        oldColor = R.color.CLR_RED;
        newColor = R.color.CLR_RED_DARK;
    }
    else if (pressedBtn == yellowBtn) {
        oldColor = R.color.CLR_YELLOW;
        newColor = R.color.CLR_YELLOW_DARK;
    }
    else if (pressedBtn == blueBtn) {
        oldColor = R.color.CLR_BLUE;
        newColor = R.color.CLR_BLUE_DARK;
    }
    else return;

    pressedBtn.setBackgroundResource(newColor);
    SystemClock.sleep(500);
    pressedBtn.setBackgroundResource(oldColor);

}
```

The problem is the color of the Button doesn't change when pressed.
I stepped with a debugger and it actually reaches the right points in the method, so that's not an issue. I think the problem is in `pressedBtn.setBackgroundResource(newColor)` but I can't understand why.

PS: Anyway, if you have a better solution to change a button color when pressed and, after a half second, change back to original color, let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use an xml file like one below, to create states for your button.

The info about attributes available is [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)
You simply copy this xml file to your drawables folder in your project, name it for example custom_button.xml, and reference it in your layout with

`android:background="@drawable/custom_button"`

Here is xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="#00ff00" />
        <stroke
            android:width="5dp"
            android:color="#ff0000"
            android:dashWidth="3dp"
            android:dashGap="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#ffffff"
            android:centerColor="#ffffff"
            android:startColor="#ffffff"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#00ff00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#ffffff"
            android:centerColor="#ffffff"
            android:startColor="#ffffff"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="5dp"
            android:color="#00ff00" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: At the moment I'm a bit busy. As soon as I'll try it I'll let you know. For now thanks.

Answer (score 17):

We were trying to implement the tab like functionality using just plain buttons in Android. I was unsuccessful to obtain the right behavior using the XML- must be doing something wrong. For instance, I could get the button color to change to yellow as long as the button was pressed, but it would go back to original color when left.

Finally, I could achieve the desired behavior by using following code in the click event handler for each of the tab buttons. Hope this helps someone having similar issue as me.

```
// Get Handle for the Tab buttons
Button btnTab1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tab1);
Button btnTab2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_tab1);

// set the colors correctly
btnTab1.setBackgroundResource(color.lightblue);
btnTab2.setBackgroundResource(color.darkblue);
```

Comment: Does this keep the standard android behavior of making it darker when you press the button?

Answer (score 4):

[setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) is expecting a drawable, not a color.  You want [setBackgroundColor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)).

Also, your colors should have at least 6 digits, #RRGGBB

I.e., for blue: #0000FF

I think what you have might be equivalent to #00000F, which is close to black...

And finally, you should never sleep in the UI thread (or change UI items not in the UI thread).  See [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for a number of different ways of using other threads.  I think that [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: nope, the buttons turn black and don't change back to their original color. at least in the emulator. when I'll finish refleshing my G1 I'll try on that