# How to set image button backgroundimage for different state?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want imagebutton with two states i) normal ii) touch(or click).

I have set **normal** image in the **imagebutton** background and I am trying to *change* **image(pressed)** from *onclick* method, but it doesn't change.

**I want that if I pressed image button then image should change from normal to pressed until I press other button but it doesn't happen**.

Can anyone suggest to me how can I do this with **selector or at run time**?

Here is my imagebuttonpanel code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:gravity="bottom"
  android:id="@+id/buttonpanel">
  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonhome"
               android:layout_width="80dp"
               android:layout_height="36dp"
               android:focusable="true" 
               android:background="@drawable/homeselector">
               </ImageButton>
  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonsearch"
               android:layout_height="36dp"
               android:layout_width="80dp"
               android:background="@drawable/searchselector"
               android:focusable="true">
               </ImageButton>>
  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonreg"
               android:layout_height="36dp"
               android:layout_width="80dp"
               android:background="@drawable/registerselector"
               android:focusable="true">
               </ImageButton>>
  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/buttonlogin"
               android:layout_height="36dp"
               android:layout_width="80dp"
               android:background="@drawable/loginselector"
               android:focusable="true">
               </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my selector xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/homehover" 
        /> <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/homehover" 
        /> <item android:drawable="@drawable/home" /> <item android:state_window_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/homehover" /> -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/homehover" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/homehover" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/homehover" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home" />

</selector>
```

And I have also tried to change image resource on ontouch and onclick event, but it does not help.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097710/android-change-button-background-programmatically/3097844#3097844). I asked a similar question back ago.

Answer (score 225):

Create an xml file in your drawable like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_sendemail_disable" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_send_email_click" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_sendemail_roll" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_sendemail" />
</selector>
```

And set images accordingly and then set this xml as background of your `imageButton`.

Comment: Correct. this will be called Selector XMLs

Comment: @Hitendra: i guess the op already knew this. the question can be interpreted as why the selector is not getting invoked.

Comment: Is state_enabled necessary?

Comment: This works for usual `Button`, but not `ImageButton`. Also this would work for `ImageButton`'s `android:src` attribute, but not `android:background`. And what is the difference between yours and OP's selector (except formatting and drawables' names) ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov For me it works very well for ImageButton and android:background.

Comment: @Trilarion, which version of Android ? I've checked this on 4.4. There were a bunch of new good stuff for selectors and colors in general in 5.0

Comment: You don't need the statement `android:state_enabled="true"`. it is the same as `if( x == 1 ){}else if( x != 1 && ... ){}`. It is guaranteed that *android:state_enabled* is *true* after the first check.

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
    }
});
```

Comment: is there any one with a idea that i can do it

Answer (score 9):

mhh. I got another solution which helped me, 'cause I just have two different sates:

- either the item is not clicked
- or it is clicked and so it will be highlighted

In my .xml I define the ImageButton like this:

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/selector" />
```

The corresponding selector file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_100_checked" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_100_unchecked"/>

</selector>
```

And in my onCreate I call:

```
final ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) value.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    OnClickListener ocl =new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View button) {
            if (button.isSelected()){
                button.setSelected(false);
            } else {
                ib.setSelected(false);
                //put all the other buttons you might want to disable here...
                button.setSelected(true);
            }
        }
    };

ib.setOnClickListener(ocl);
//add ocl to all the other buttons
```

done. hope this helps. took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 8):

Hi try the following code it will be useful to you,

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewButton)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewButton)).setImageResource(R.drawable.image_over);

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewButton)).setImageResource(R.drawable.image_normal);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: actually, this also doesn't really work, if action_up happens on a different view. try using event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL instead of ACTION_UP.

Answer (score 3):

i think you problem is not the selector file.

you have to add

```
<imagebutton ..
    android:clickable="true"
/>
```

to your image buttons.

by default the **onClick is handled at the listitem level** (parent). and the imageButtons dont recieve the onClick.

when you add the above attribute the image button will receive the event and the selector will be used.

check this [**POST**](http://appfulcrum.com/?p=311) which explains the same for checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is more a segmentedbutton than an imagebutton list.

here http://blog.bookworm.at/2010/10/segmented-controls-in-android.html is an example on how to do so. The basic idea is to customize RadioButton instead of ImageButton, since the RadioButton will have the checked state you need

Comment: no.. I dun think that's what he wanted. segmented control is entirely different UI element. he wants 1 button that changes state.

Answer (score 1):

if you want pressed image button then image should be change from normal to pressed

**But I best way will be to customize the RadioButton and use them in a group. I have see an example of that.**
Sorry I did not remember that link.

but if you want to avoid that.
You need to add this to your selector.xml

Once Done. Just got to your code and add this

```
public void onClick ( View v ) {
    myImageButton.setSelected ( true ) ;
 }
```

You will see the result. But you have to mange the states which button was recently press. So that you can set

```
  myOLDImageButton.setSelected ( false ) ;
```

I suggest you to put all button reference in a array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `CompoundButton`? CompoundButton has the checkable property that exactly matches your need. Replace ImageButtons with these.

```
  <CompoundButton android:id="@+id/buttonhome"
                  android:layout_width="80dp"
                  android:layout_height="36dp"
                  android:background="@drawable/homeselector"/>
```

Change selector xml to the following. May need some modification but be sure to use `state_checked` in place of `state_pressed`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/homehover" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/homehover" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/homehover" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home" />

</selector>
```

In `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` you need to check and uncheck other based on your conditions.

```
 mButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // Uncheck others. 
        }
   }
});
```

Similarly set a `OnCheckedChangeListener` to each button, which will uncheck other buttons when it is checked. Hope this Helps.

Comment: You can't use CompoundButton directly in XML as it is an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

you can create selector file in res/drawable

example:
res/drawable/selector_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_enabled" />
</selector>
```

and in layout activity, fragment or etc

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_bg_rectangle_black"/>
```