# Button expose effect android

Tags: android

following link has some button at the top like :: "DISEASES" , "FOOD & NUTRITION" , "PHYSICAL ACTIVITY"
http://www.bam.gov/sub_yourbody/yourbody_smilestyle.html

when you focus it it will grow and remove from it it will small 
so question is how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is set [selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state/4755934#4755934) for your button as shown in my previous answer.

And depending on your requirement set drawable larger than the normal ones for that particular state , that will create the same effect

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that there's a huge difference between a mouse as a pointing device and your finger. A mouse can easily hover across these buttons to give you the effect, but it doesn't work as well with a finger, as you'd need to slide your finger across the buttons to get the effect - and who slides their finger across buttons instead of just pressing them?

Anyway, I suppose you could create an `OnTouchListener` for your `Buttons`, and perhaps throw in some animations to get the effects.

But - like I said - I don't see a reason to do this. It seems utterly unnecessary.

Comment: but i am confuse in graphically. is there any them or problematically need to increase my button size in scope of `OnTouchListener`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: lets assume,you need to give those kind of effect. so simply you increase your button size run-time.but is there any theme attribute that give real effect?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to program your own animation to complete the effect.

Comment: @J_andr you can say like that