# Android: Adding an Image Background to a Button in XML File

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set image button backgroundimage for different state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state)

I have the following declaring how a button should be drawn (uabutton.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:endColor="#e9e8e9"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#ffffff"
                android:startColor="#b9b9b9"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#f0aa9f"
                android:endColor="#e21f00"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff8a0e"
                android:endColor="#e9e8e9"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>    
    </item>
</selector>
```

My question is, I would like to add an image to the background of each button.  Where, if anywhere, in the above would I add the image.

The button is added a to a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/aboutualocationbtn"
    android:text="Menu"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/uabutton"/>
```

Comment: Mike its works  fine whts prblm you have?

Comment: @Samir  As stated, I would like to know where to add the image to the button.

Comment: Are you trying to keep your gradient and use a picture also? Or use an image file instead of your gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a [Layer List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) drawable.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:background="@drawable/uabutton"
```

is pointing to a file called uabutton in your drawables folder as the background

ie uabutton.jpg or uabutton.png

Comment: I know that.  I need that file to for the gradients and shape of the buttons.  I need to add a small subtle image to the button also.