# How to give Flashing Effect between Two images in Android?

Tags: android, animation

I have two images(Light Red and Dark Red) for the button and i want to give Flashing Effect to that button that initially it glows from light-red to Dark-red and then when it pressed, its state will be changed to dark red. i try to sort out the Solution for this but every-where i see Fade-in and Fade-out solution using one image, but i want to use both images.

Please let me know if any function exists there for giving Flashing Effect between two images or i will have to make it manually.

Answer (score 1):

For this I think you have to use customized xml drawable for your button,
And for different state of button you can use different images, to apply style

Try this,

example:

XML file saved at res/drawable/button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
<item android:state_pressed="true"          
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->    
<item android:state_focused="true"          
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->    
<item android:state_hovered="true"          
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- hovered -->    
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />  <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This layout XML applies the state list drawable to a Button:

```
<Button    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
           android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

For more info look at [Android - Drawable Style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

And nice example [Adding Gradient Effects to Android Button](http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/03/adding-gradient-effects-to-android.html).

SO post [how to set image button backgroundimage for different state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work with associating [`Animation`](http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/08/10/Making-a-simple-custom-Android-UI-animation.aspx)s to `Buttons`.

Here are some links to tutorials :

- [link](http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/)
- [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2tiLqICpaE)