# How to achieve in android something like on_hover in css?

Tags: android

How to achieve in android something like on_hover in css ? I want to images in buttons be more light when touch. I have those lightier images but I don't know where to save them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state/4755934#4755934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this below selector.xml and put your image  in your drawable folder.
call your button background as android:background="@drawable/selector".

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/darkimage" >
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/darkimage" >
</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/lighterimage" >
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

You will get something like this:

```
@Override 
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { 

        if(motionEvent == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE){
            //change image
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false; 
        }
}
```

Just take a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)