# How to overlay play and pause button?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do i make my pause and play button overlay from one another? It just means that, when I press the button to pause the pause button will appear and when i press the button again the play button will appear.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#A9E2F3"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >



 <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="Audio Streaming"
        android:textSize="43sp" />   

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play"
            android:id="@+id/button_play" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pause"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/button_play"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button_play"
            android:id="@+id/button_pause" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause"/>

             </RelativeLayout>
```

I dont even know if I've using the correct layout, isit relative, frame or linear?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: But why do you overlay this Buttons? Instead of used `ImageButton` and change `ImageButton` resources as per your need...

Comment: @MD so if i use `ImageButton` i can overlay two buttons?

Comment: One button, different images.

Comment: @ElDuderino do you have any links on how to do that?

Comment: You will find the answer in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state

Comment: just take one bool and set value true if play and on pause false then set condition if true then set button text pause otherwise play...

Comment: @Pranav i dont get you, can you show me some example codes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use only one button as toggle when you click it make flag true and set its text as play if flag is true then make it false and set its text as pause and so on...

as per flag write your code in if codition of flags

enjoy coding