# Effect for ImageButton in android

Tags: android, imagebutton, effects

I want to create effects for ImageButton. For example, it will change color when clicked...How I do it? I want to do this in .xml file. Can you help me! Thank you!
I tried to create the state.xml file as follwing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_0" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_ac" />

</selector>
```

However, I can't set background for ImageButton. The error like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state) maybe it's what your are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a drawable like below and name it as `btn_drawable`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_disable" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_click" />

    </selector>
```

This is for an example,Like this you can add the `<item/>` according to your needs and state of the image button.
Then set the drawable as image button background.

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_drawable"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I still can't set background for ImageButton. btn_drawable doesn't appear in background list, so I can't choose. Can you help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do it to add the "android:background" attribut to your ImageButton and set a drawable.

> Your layout

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_btn"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_drawable"/>
```

> btn_drawable.xml

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:state_pressed="true"
              android:drawable="@drawable/blue"
              />
        <item android:state_focused="true"
              android:drawable="@drawable/white"
              />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/green" />
    </selector>
```

In that code above you set a different drawable when your ImageButton is pressed (state_pressed), focused (state_focus) or when is normal (not pressed and not focused).

[Here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html) you can find with more detail.