# How do I make a round edged button in Android Studio with the button using my image file as background?

Tags: android, android-layout

I recently learnt how to make a round edged button. But I am able to make buttons only with a plain background. Now, I want to make a button that uses an image file from my computer as it's background. How do I make it?

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state) out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
make a new Drawable Resource file inside your drawable and paste the following code

//For Displaying Transparent Rounder Border to Button or ET or TV

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#30647A" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp" />

</shape>
```

and to you button in your XML do this

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/data_linear"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/resource_name"
            android:text="@string/next_btn"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this to make image as background of your button:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
    }
});
```

Second method:
 You can define imagebutton in your xml file and give source to it like this:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `myButton.xml` having `android:drawable` as background

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img1" />

    <shape >
        <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <gradient
            android:angle="225"
            android:startColor="#DD2ECCFA"
            android:endColor="#DD000000"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
    </shape>
    </layer-list>
```

And It's your Button using that drawable as background

```
   <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:background="@drawable/myButton"
        android:text="OpenContact"
        />
```