# Android transform ImageView to Button programmiticaly with two images and onClickListener

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener, drawable

I want to create a button animation with two image on an ImageView **programmiticaly only** and by using onClickListener. I have two image that i can set with setImageResource() fonction but i don't know how to play the button animation before the button action launches.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state

Answer (score 0):

Please, could you explain a bit more what you are wanting? Do you want to replace the ImageButton resource when you click on it? You can achieve it setting the `OnClickListener`

`new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      imageButtonView.setImageResource(idOfTheNewResource);
    }
  };`

Is this what you are wanting?

Comment: I actually make this but, my shapeview start another activity and when i come back in my precedent activity which contain my button, it stay with the ressource that i apply before. What i want is to resotre the first image with setImageResource() after i change of activity.

Comment: The first image is the state when the imageview isn't pressed and the other when it is. I want to restore the first image just after realise my redirection (or my click, or in my click before start the redirection).

Comment: Now I understand what you want, I'll comment your question.